# Using Gravity Forms to upload media into library, then attach to post

Tags: uploads, media-library, front-end, plugin-gravity-forms

I have a simple site with two Gravity Forms, both of which allow users to upload media.

I'm looking for some simple code that:

(a) inserts all uploaded media into the Media Library and not the default Gravity Forms folder
(b) attaches media to pages. Form 1 attach to page 1, form 2 to page 2.

I've found a few similar posts, but nothing simple that does exactly what I need.

I guess I'd use something like

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_1', 'after_submission', 10, 2 );
```

and

```
wp_insert_attachment
```

Because I only have two forms, would something simple in the functions.php that adds media to the library then depending on which form was used attaches to posts work?

Answer (score 0):

My plugin Gravity Forms Media Library provides this functionality for Gravity Forms: https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-media-library/

Comment: Sidenote.... that is a premium plugin, i.e. it is not free. Amazing features though.